# SQL query not returning records where related record is inactive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have three `Account` ABC, DEF and XYZ. 
ABC have two Inactive `Contracts`. 
DEF don't have any contract. 
XYZ have two contracts (one active and one inactive).

Following query is returning me output as following.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║name║ accountId    ║Count ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║DEF ║ 554-050-4876 ║  0   ║
║XYZ ║ 111-000-4345 ║  1   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

But I am expecting the result as follwing:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║name║ accountId    ║Count ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║ABC ║ 244-5677-444 ║  0   ║
║DEF ║ 554-050-4876 ║  0   ║
║XYZ ║ 111-000-4345 ║  1   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

Means, query should return all the `Accounts` with the number of active `Contracts`. If there is no Contract exist of an account or only inactive contracts are their. Query should return 0 in Count column.

```
SELECT 
    a.name 
    , a.accountid 
    , COUNT(c.contractid) AS  'Count' --Number Active Of Contracts
FROM FilteredAccount AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredContract AS c
    ON a.accountid = c.accountid
WHERE a.statecode = 0 -- Active
    AND a.customertypecode = 3 -- Active
    AND a.name IN ('ABC','XYZ')
    AND (c.statecode = 2 or c.statecode is null)
GROUP BY a.name , a.accountid;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a left outer join on `c` and then you include it in the where clause. This makes it an inner join. Try moving `AND (c.statecode ...`  to the `ON`.

Comment: +1 for using filtered views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all the `JOIN` criteria into the `ON` clause: at the moment you have filtering terms in the `WHERE` which override your `left outer join`.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    a.name 
    , a.accountid 
    , COUNT(c.contractid) AS  'Count' --Number Active Of Contracts
FROM FilteredAccount AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredContract AS c
    ON (c.statecode = 2 or c.statecode is null) and a.accountid = c.accountid
WHERE a.statecode = 0 -- Active
    AND a.customertypecode = 3 -- Active
    AND a.name IN ('ABC','XYZ')
GROUP BY a.name , a.accountid;
```